# read: read error: 0: Resource temporarily unavailable after mpirun in bash script

Tags: multithreading, bash

I have tried to find the solution online  for my issue. I have narrowed it down to mpirun causing the issues as merely invoking the executable does not return issues. I have tried to redirect outputs but to no luck.

I receive the error in the title for every read I attempt to do after I run mpirun. Here are the relevant line of code.

```
    mpirun -np $numcores  $dir/vasp
```

What does work is ./vasp, however it is much slower with just one core. For whatever reason invoking the above ruins this and causes the following read commands asking the user for a value to fail.

Comment: Why are you running `mpirun` in background?

Comment: I am just in the habit from when I normally use it. I still receive the same error if I run it without the &. I also get the same error when I run it without 2> /dev/null